# How can I return the result of my Node controller to my application through AJAX?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

This is my controller code

```
module.exports.key_i = function(req, res, next) {
  // console.log("We are here in webserver key_i");

  var k = req.body.KEY;
  // console.log(k);
  var requestOptions = {
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/key_i',
    method: 'POST',
    json:{
      key: k
    }
  }

  request(requestOptions, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      return res.status(500).send(error);
    } else {
      // console.log("Key_i "+body[0].price);
      var tt = { pp: body[0] };
    } 
  });
}
```

Here `body[0]` contains the desired result. How can I pass this to my AJAX response?

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:3000/ajo",
  method: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    KEY: xy
  }),
  success: function(response) {
    console.log("Now response in topbt.js is");
    console.log(response);    
  }
});
```

I want `body[0]` to be my response. How can I do this?

Comment: key is a numeric value?

Comment: is the API `http://localhost:3000/api/key_i` working on same server or in different server?

Answer (score 0):

you should use `res` (maybe `.json`) to return back to your controller (route). so your frontend application can get the response from the express route.

Documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the request that you are making will return *JSON*

#### controller.js

```
module.exports.key_i = function(req, res, next) {
  
  ...

  request(requestOptions, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      return res.status(500).send(error);
    }
    // assuming { pp: body[0] }; <- This is the object you want to send in response
    res.send({ pp: body[0] };)
     
  });
}
```